# SauceLabs Pass/Fail using behat

Tags: behat, saucelabs

I am trying to add Pass/Fail status in Saucelabs whenever I run an Automated test but I can't figure out how shall I do it. I use Behat - Selenium Driver. I read the documentation but it didn't help me.

I tried to use the Saucelabs Rest API guide and I launch in my console the following

```
curl -X PUT \
-s -d '{"passed":true}' \
-u https://USERNAME:APIKEY@saucelabs.com/rest/v1/users/USERNAME
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the session Id
ownCloud uses:

`curl -X PUT -s -d "{\"passed\": $PASSED}" -u $SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/$SAUCE_USERNAME/jobs/$SAUCELABS_SESSIONID`

see: https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/master/tests/travis/start_ui_tests.sh#L235

and this Id is pulled from the URL: https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/master/tests/ui/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php#L171
but there might be better ways of getting it